様々な画像を使用して重量予測を行いたいがうまくいきません。
MATLABでRGB画像とDepth画像を使用して梨の重量を推定するプロジェクトに取り組んでいます。当初はトレーニングに正面の画像とDepth画像を使用していましたが、現在は それに加え梨の左または右に約90度移動した場所から撮影した画像を含めることで精度を向上したいと考えています。
これらの新しい画像に対応するようにコードを変更しようとしましたが、いくつか問題に直面しています。
以下の点を変更したいと思います。

梨の画像は、正面、正面から約 90 度左または右に移動した画像、および Depth 画像を使用します。
すべてのデータをデータストアに格納します。

以下は使用したコードです。
cd 'RGB front file path'
folder_name = pwd;
XImageTrainFront = imageDatastore(folder_name);
cd 'RGB side file path'
folder_name = pwd;
XImageTrainSide = imageDatastore(folder_name);
cd 'Depth file path'
folder_name = pwd;
XDispTrain = imageDatastore(folder_name);
YTrain = [ data ]; % weight labels
YTrain = arrayDatastore(YTrain);
% Combine datasets
ds = combine(XImageTrainFront, XImageTrainSide, XDispTrain, YTrain);
dsrand = shuffle(ds);
dsVali = partition(dsrand, 10, 1);
dsTest = partition(dsrand, 10, 2);
ds1=partition(dsrand,10,3);
ds2=partition(dsrand,10,4);
ds3=partition(dsrand,10,5);
ds4=partition(dsrand,10,6);
ds5=partition(dsrand,10,7);
ds6=partition(dsrand,10,8);
ds7=partition(dsrand,10,9);
ds8=partition(dsrand,10,10);
dsTrain=combine(ds1,ds2,ds3,ds4,ds5,ds6,ds7,ds8,ReadOrder="sequential");
YTest = readall(dsTest);
YTest = YTest(:,4); 
YTest = cell2mat(YTest);
cd 'path to googlenet300400_multiple.mat'
load googlenet300400_multiple.mat
miniBatchSize = 16;
options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'MiniBatchSize', miniBatchSize, ...
    'MaxEpochs', 300, ...
    'InitialLearnRate', 1e-7, ...
    'LearnRateSchedule', 'piecewise', ...
    'LearnRateDropFactor', 0.1, ...
    'LearnRateDropPeriod', 30, ...
    'Shuffle', 'every-epoch', ...
    'ValidationData', dsVali, ...
    'ValidationFrequency', 50, ...
    'Plots', 'training-progress', ...
    'Verbose', true);
net = trainNetwork(dsTrain, lgraph_2, options);
YPredicted = predict(net, dsTest);
predictionError = YTest - YPredicted;
squares = predictionError.^2;
rmse = sqrt(mean(squares));
figure
scatter(YPredicted, YTest, '+');
xlabel("Predicted Value");
ylabel("True Value");
hold on;
plot([100 550], [100 550], 'r--');

次のエラーメッセージが表示されました。
Error using: trainNetwork (line 191)
Invalid training data. The output size of the last layer ([1 1 1]) is the response size ([1 1 360000])
does not match.
Error: newcord2 (line 93)
net = trainNetwork(dsTrain, lgraph_2, options);
Error using: nnet.cnn.LayerGraph/replaceLayer (line 300)
Layer 'finalLayerName' does not exist.
Error: newcord2 (line 85)
lgraph_2 = replaceLayer(lgraph_2, 'finalLayerName', finalLayer);

エラー メッセージを修正して、プログラムを正常に実行する方法を教えてください。
googlenet300400_multiple.mat(lgraph_2)の内容です。
Properties of <a href="matlab:helpPopup('nnet.cnn.LayerGraph')" style="font-weight:bold">LayerGraph</a>:
InputNames: {'imageinput' 'imageinput_1'}
OutputNames: {'regressionoutput'}
Layers: [284×1 nnet.cnn.layer.Layer]
Connections: [337×2 table]


「これらの新しい画像に対応するようにコードを変更しようとしましたが、いくつか問題に直面しています。」とのことですが質問があります。１．「新しい画像」を使用する前は問題なくコードは動作していたのでしょうか？　２．「いくつか問題」とありますが提示されているエラー以外にも問題が発生しているのでしょうか？　３．Matlabは詳しくないのですが、一般に学習データを追加した際にエラーが発生することはないかと思います。追加したデータに問題がある可能性はありませんか？
